# 2nd User Accounts for Guests

Tags: windows-10

How do I add **a picture (NOT A PHOTO) in Windows 10** to a Guest, any Guest USER ACCOUNT or the **2nd User Account** that I have set up for my guests in case they need to use my laptop to go on the internet?

I'm not asking about my, User Account, in which I have inserted a photo of myself.

Please provide a step-by-step solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

1) log in to the 2nd user account

2) find the picture you want to use

3) set the picture as the account picture, as per [usual](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17152/windows-10-change-your-account-picture):

a. Select the Start Start symbol button, then select Settings‌  > Accounts  > Your info‌

b. Under Create your picture, choose Browse for one. Select the picture you found earlier.